# Conditional formatting using multiple conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, formatting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vimnq.png)

Need help to know how to format cells based on below condition.
If %C%1="Automated", %B%3="Nextgen", C3>0.0001 then color green

My condition is only applying on 1st row, not on all selected cells

=AND($C3="Automated",B1="Nextgen",C3>0.0001) then color green

=AND($C3="Automated",B1="Nextgen",C3>0.0001) then color green

Comment: For high quality questions, it's better to consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) guide